# Duplicate a CSV row and give it a new header name through PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv

I have a CSV file with 20 rows and load them with

```
str_getcsv
```

Now i want to duplicate a row called "main_image" (position 10) twice and give the names "small_image" (should be position 11) and "thumb_image" (should be position 12) to the headers (first line) so i have a headers line with 22 rows.

Comment: Parse your CSV into an array and massage it.

Comment: @angelcool.net thats the part, i can parse it into an array but don't know how to duplicate the row (and all the cell's beneath it) and put it right after the original row.

Comment: I am confused.  Its a CSV file, there are no cells beneath it.  Please provide a sample of your CSV file.